# Conditional DAG Order based on Condition (For Loop with If Condition)

Tags: python, airflow

Trying to set the graph order based on conditional arguments within a for loop.

In the example below, I want to create 3 sets of operators based on different colours, two of the colour sets follow a direct order, although the green one has a different order, with an additional operator.

My code is structured as below:

```py
for colour in ['red','green','amber']
        #operator definitions
        first_step = operator(
            task_id=f'step_first_{colour}'
            <params based on colour>
        )
        last_step = operator(
            task_id=f'step_last_{colour}'
            <params based on colour>
        )
        green_step = operator(
            task_id=f'step_{colour}'
            <params based on green only>
        )

        #graph definition
        if colour == 'green':
            first_step >> green_step >> last_step
        else:
            first_step >> last_step
```

Running the above results in the following error:

> Dependancy first_step last_step already registered.

Comment: Can you share how you're setting ``task_id`` in each task? You can never set a dependency between the same two tasks twice, so I'm guessing you're not correctly giving ``first_step`` and ``last_step`` a unique task id based on its color.

Comment: Using the colour variable in the task id assignment: `task_id = f'step_{colour}'`